# Choose the option in html5 select (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to make a very simple jquery plugin, but my code working only for Firefox Browser. How to can I write this code other so that it works in google chrome, opera and other browsers?

If I choose `option value='business'`, remove the `is--hidden` class in `.address--company`, but If I choose `option value='private'`, add `is--hidden` to `.address--company` class.

HTML:

```
<div class="address--customertype">
  <div class="select-field">
    <select name="address[additional][customer_type]" required="required" aria-required="true" class="is--required">
      <option value="private" selected="selected">Klient indywidualny</option>
      <option value="business">Firma</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="address--company is--hidden">...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select[name="address[additional][customer_type]"] option[value="business"]').click(function() {
  if ($('.address--company').hasClass('is--hidden')) {
    $('.address--company').removeClass('is--hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You mainly need to assign a `change` event to listen for the options changes in `select` dropdown to make it work as you expect.
2. Your jQuery selector is also incorrect.
3. You can assign class and remove class based on the value `private` and `business`
4. Since there are only two `option`, you can use a simple `if-else` for that.
5. In addition, add `.trigger('change')` to change the class accordingly based on selected default value.

```js
$('select[name="address[additional][customer_type]"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'private') {
    $('.address--company').addClass('is--hidden');
  } else {
    $('.address--company').removeClass('is--hidden');
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.is--hidden {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="address--customertype">
  <div class="select-field">
    <select name="address[additional][customer_type]" required="required" aria-required="true" class="is--required">
      <option value="private" selected="selected">Klient indywidualny</option>
      <option value="business">Firma</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="address--company is--hidden">............</div>
```

Comment: @JsStorm2 use `.trigger('change')`. I have also updated the description and code in the above answer. Check it